# How to convert from string ( ASCII type) to UTF-8 in C#

Tags: c#, string, encoding, utf-8

I have problem when i convert from my string to UTF-8 in C#. These are details:
I have string as parameter of a method:

```
void testConvert(string input)
```

And in other method, i call it:

```
testConvert("\u9ad9");
```

Now, i want to covert it to UTF-8, but because in C#, they realize a slash "\" and replace it to "\\", so my string will be "\\u9ad9".
With this string, i do not know how to convert it to UTF-8, because if i use it for input in System.Text.UTF8Encoding, it won't recognize. It only process with "\u9ad9".

I try some methods that i searched in this site, but it does not work.

Please help me to resolve this problem !
Thanks and Best Regards.

Comment: Can you show the code of testConvert?

Comment: please provide some sample inputs and expected outputs

Comment: Hi, i think testConvert is not important here, beacause the problem is the format of String in C#. I just call it for  parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All strings in C# are encoded as UTF16 Little Endian, even if you read a file in UTF8, it gets converted to UTF16LE, don't fight the system, if you need to convert it to UTF8 before writing to a file (there are options to select the target encoding) or sending to a webservice (you will need to send as raw bytes), we need to know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, thanks for your reply. As you say, i'm parsing through WebService, so i need to convert. And now i have other solution. Thanks for your helping. Best Regards !